# Java pattern mapper

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, терминология

Изучаю некоторые паттерны и вот остановился на паттерне мап.

Что значит мапить данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«[map](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/map)» это английское слово, которое переводится как «карта».

В математике термин применяется в значении «функция», «отображение». В программировании используется более и менее произвольно в случаях когда происходит преобразование чего-либо во что-либо:

- [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) — ассоциативный массив, структура данных.
- [Device Mapper](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper) — виртуальное устройство, для обобщения работы с другими устройствами.
- [`Map`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map) — функция, которая применяется ко всем элементам множества.
- [MapReduce](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) — модель распределенных выражений
- и т.п.

> что значи маппить данные

Как правило это означает, что данные каким-либо образом преобразовываются. Из-за столь широкого использования термина у него нет одного общепринятого значения. Обычно значение ясно из контекста:

> ... маппим записи в БД из набора данных к списку сущностей
>   ... маппим множество объектов через заданный оператор

Эти примеры допустимы в разговорной речи. В официальной документации было бы уместно заменить «маппить» на «отобразить/преобразовать/привести».

Если кто-либо говорит, что нужно «маппить данные» без контекста, то нужно уточнить требования и выяснить, что именно имеется ввиду. Попросите привести примеры исходных данных и ожидаемого результата.

Если человек категорически отказывается уточнить, что имеется ввиду, то это может означать, что он не понимает что именно нужно сделать и пытается это скрыть, используя неоднозначный термин. В этом случае рекоммендую ответить, что данные «не маппятся» и в дальнейшем воздержаться от деловых и личных контактов с таким человеком.

Comment: В примере с пользователями и правами должно быть "match", а не "map".

Comment: @Qwertiy пример отвлеченный и, пожалуй, неудачный, может быть и то и другое. Псевдокод: `usersList.map(u => RightsService.retrieveRights(u.getUserId()))`

Comment: В таком случае я не вижу разницы между примерами.

Comment: @Qwertiy второе слово в примерах разное :) Отсутствие принципиальной разницы вызвано аморфностью примеров. Подумаю, как это можно улучшить, спасибо за замечание!